# How to upload a picture in android through JSON, my current method takes a long time

Tags: android, json, image

The question that I am trying to have answered is what tweaks need to be done to my code to make it faster for the upload of the picture to the server?

My code currently takes the picture and stores it in a byte array and then changes it to a base64 string which is then put into a JSON Object and sent along with some text. However, this takes at least 30 seconds to a minute...

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if (v == uploadImageButton) {
            // below allows you to open the phones gallery
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
        }
        if (v == postWardrobe) {
            // validate input and that something was entered
            if (nameField.getText().toString().length() < 1
                    || colorField.getText().toString().length() < 1
                    || sizeField.getText().toString().length() < 1
                    || quantityField.getText().toString().length() < 1) {

                // missing required info (null was this but lets see)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please complete all sections!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            } else {
                JSONObject dataWardrobe = new JSONObject();

                try {
                    dataWardrobe.put("name", nameField.getText().toString());
                    dataWardrobe.put("brand", brandField.getText().toString());
                    dataWardrobe.put("category", typeField.getSelectedItem()
                            .toString());
                    dataWardrobe.put("color", colorField.getText().toString());
                    dataWardrobe.put("weather", seasonField.getSelectedItem()
                            .toString());
                    dataWardrobe.put("size", sizeField.getText().toString());
                    dataWardrobe.put("quantity", quantityField.getText()
                            .toString());
                    dataWardrobe.put("picture", encodedImage);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // make progress bar visible
                progressBarField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Log.e("check uri", "selected " + buri);
                // execute the post request
                new dataSend().execute(dataWardrobe);

                // new ImageUploadTask().execute(buri);

            }
        }

    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1 && null != data) {

            decodeUri(data.getData());
        }
    }

    public void decodeUri(Uri uri) {
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFD = null;
        try {

            parcelFD = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            FileDescriptor imageSource = parcelFD.getFileDescriptor();

            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(imageSource, null, o);

            // the new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                    break;
                }
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(imageSource, null, o2);

            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            // encode image into a Base64 to send as a JSON string
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

            // can take off below just shows path
            buri = "" + uri;
            imageTextSelect.setText("select : " + uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // handle errors
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle errors
        } finally {
            if (parcelFD != null)
                try {
                    parcelFD.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // ignored
                }
        }
    }

private class dataSend extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Integer, Double> {

        protected Double doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postData(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
            progressBarField.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(wardrobe.this, "info sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            progressBarField.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        public void postData(JSONObject dataWardrobe) {

            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:3000/wardrobe");

            try {
                Log.v("trying data", "prep");
                // add data
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(dataWardrobe.toString());
                se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        "application/json"));
                httppost.setEntity(se);

                // execute http post request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: JSON is a very poor way to represent binary data. You'd be better off figuring out how to do binary uploads, maybe through WebDAV?

Comment: Would I be able to send it along with the JSON info or somehow together, because currently I am sending info back to the server as JSON and reading the key:value pair

Comment: You would post binary data (WebDAV or FTP) to upload images separately, then post to the server a JSON of the URL along with your metadata.

Comment: Any examples or such that you can include links to and what not, specifically for using Android Java to do it

Comment: Apache commons works well for FTP: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/, and Sardine for WebDAV: https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine. If you google, you'll find usage examples.

Comment: I heard ftp is not suitable for many things, is multipartentitybuilder a better source?

Comment: It may not be suitable for many things, but it *is* suitable for uploading pictures. I'd still lean toward WebDAV. MultipartEntityBuilder encodes binary data for http POSTs, so you'd have the same issue you currently have with it. However, you might be able to move the encoding into an async task or spin off a separate thread. These patterns are well-documented and certainly exceed the scope of comments here.

Answer (score 1):

There are 94 Unicode characters which can be represented as one byte according to the JSON spec (if your JSON is transmitted as UTF-8). With that in mind, I think the best you can do space-wise is base85 which represents four bytes as five characters. However, this is only a 7% improvement over base64, it's more expensive to compute, and implementations are less common than for base64 so it's probably not a win.

You could also simply map every input byte to the corresponding character in U+0000-U+00FF, then do the minimum encoding required by the JSON standard to pass those characters; the advantage here is that the required decoding is nil beyond builtin functions, but the space efficiency is bad -- a 105% expansion (if all input bytes are equally likely) vs. 25% for base85 or 33% for base64.

Final verdict: base64 wins, in my opinion, on the grounds that it's common, easy, and not bad enough to warrant replacement

Comment: Isn't JSON UTF-8 only?

Comment: Is there a better solution then to make it faster, like maybe not using base64 or JSON but being able to post it along with the JSON Object being created at the same time (since all the info has to be sent together?

Comment: Jpeg data doesn't compress very well, and the OP's question was how to *reduce* the time spent on encoding, not to reduce the amount of data sent at the expense of encoding time.